# AutoComplete in Jquery using easyautocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I already make EastAutoComplete work on my test page via this code:
http://easyautocomplete.com/guide

```
<body>
      <input id="basics"/>
 <script>
var options = {
    data: ["blue", "green", "pink", "red", "yellow"]
};

$("#basics").easyAutocomplete(options);
</script>
</body>
```

But when I'm transferring my code to my project it doesnt work,
Here's my input text,

```
<input type="text" id="basics" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Renovation, Plumming, Welder, Carpent, Driver , Cleaner Etc...">
```

here is my full sourecode: http://pastebin.com/TnUyzPnv

Comment: Hello, put your example in codepen? Because I tried and function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your code after all the javascript files are loaded by the browser. So put this code inside:

```
$(function() {});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        data: ["blue", "green", "pink", "red", "yellow"]
    };

    $("#basics").easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```